# EXCEL - How to have rows in one sheet update from another including insert/delete

Tags: excel, excel-formula, insert, row, delete-row

I know others want to do this:
When a new row is inserted in Sheet_A (or deleted), have a new row inserted in Sheet_B.

I have a worksheet that is my master list of employees.  I have a second worksheet that is a record of all training conducted.  When a new employee is added to the master worksheet, I want the training worksheet to insert a new row at the same location.

Clearly, I can do this with a Macro, but would prefer not to.  Is there any kind of built in function within Excel for keeping two sheets synced?

Comment: No, there is no inbuilt function to do this.

Comment: As I suspected.  A useful function overlooked for years.  I guess I'm writing a macro.

Comment: But why do it that way? Do a count of the employees and then bring back that number of records... That is how I do it for 6 classes of students from 1 cohort. Test for the ID in each cell, if it is blank then don't bring back data...

Comment: Turn your master list into a table. Create a query based on the master table. Use the query table as your training record by adding additional columns. Whenever the master list is changed you can refresh the training query/table to add the changes.

Comment: @K753 I thought about power query as well but the problem is that if the OP is manually adding information to Sheet_B, some information (if not all) will be distorted once he refreshes Sheet_A after making changes. A safer way would be using macro I guess.